# Find characteristic function of variable given a conditional distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Given
$$ X \sim \operatorname {Erlang}(n,1)$$ and $$ Y|X=x \sim\operatorname {Po}(x) .$$
How do I find the characteristic function of $Y$?

I did start with this:
$$
\phi_{Y|X=x}(t) = E[e^{itY} | X=x] = e^{x(e^{it}-1)} $$by the Po(x)-distribution.
$$
\phi_{Y}(t) = E[e^{itY}] = E[E[e^{itY}|X]] = E[e^{X(e^{it}-1)}]
$$

But to solve that expected value gives me a really complicated integral which I can't solve. Am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE:
I followed your hint with the integral, but I'm unable to solve it still:
$$
E[e^{X(e^{it}-1)}] = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{x(e^{it}-1)}f_x(x) dx = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{x(e^{it}-2)} x^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \{\frac{e^{x(e^{it}-2)}}{e^{n}}[(ex)^{n-1} - (n-1)(ax)^{n-2} + (n-1)(n-2)(ax)^{n-3} -... + (-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!]\}_0^\infty
$$
But I have no idea how to simplify that to the final result you spoke of... Or am I doing any step wrong?

Comment: The hint given below yields unnecessarily complicated computations since the goal is not to compute a primitive of the function, simply the value of its integral on $(0,+\infty)$. Rather note that for every $z$ with positive real part, the change of variable $t=zx$ yields $$\int_0^\infty e^{-zx}x^{n-1}dx=z^{-n}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{n-1}dt=z^{-n}\Gamma(n),$$ and use this for $z=2-e^{it}$ to deduce that $$E(e^{X(\exp(it)-1)})=(2-e^{it})^{-n}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved it!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, here is a hint to solve the integral

$$
   \int e^{ax} x^{n}  = \frac{e^{ax}}{a^{n+1}} \left[ (ax)^n - n(ax)^{n-1}+ n(n-1)(ax)^{n-2} - \dots + (-1)^nn! \right]
$$
and your final result should be
$$
   \frac{(-1)^n}{(e^{it}-2)^n}
$$

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I couldn't solve it though please see my update!